# Force HTTPS in htaccess while also only making public folder accessible

Tags: .htaccess

This `.htaccess` file is in my /public_html/ folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this `.htaccess` is inside my /public_html/public/ folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I need to add a rule like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I get an issue with it redirecting too many times.

I need to still use the public folder as my root and the front controller inside /public/ but I want to direct all traffic to https.

Can someone help me understand how to go about this?

Do I need to change my rewrite rules pertaining to the /public/ folder?

Comment: What you have should work. Try chanding this line: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` to `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on` and also change `%{SERVER_NAME}` to `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: I get an inital redirect error still. I'm confused about where to place it and if I'm altering any lines like the ones with the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]`
`RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Add `http->https` rule in `.htaccess` of `/public_html/public/` folder as this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R=301,NE,L]

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Make sure to test in a new browser or completely clear browser cache.**

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I still get redirection errors

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.